# No interface method setExtras

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't understand this error. When I start my app I got this error all the time:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method setExtras(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V in class Landroid/database/Cursor; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.database.Cursor' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
    at com.myapp.app.idapp.IdAppProvedor.query(IdAppProvedor.java:93)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:950)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:210)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
```

This is the code where error occurs:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayList("ALIAS", alias);
cursor.setExtras(b);
```

Extremely simple. Why Android is throwing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right imports?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.database.Cursor;
```

try checking you dependencies and making sure they are up to date